# Chrome packaged app: Sandbox + loading data files?

Tags: d3.js, google-chrome-app

I have been playing with wrapping an existing web site/app into a chrome packaged app.

It is a d3.js app that loads data files asynchronously via d3.csv, d3.json, etc.

It seems that the d3 code is doing some stuff that the (unmodifiable?) CSP for packaged apps does not allow.  I imagine some of the other libraries I'm using might do so as well.  So you have to "sandbox" the page/app to allow this. However, this means you can't make async calls to get the data files.  You can't make jquery async calls synchronously, either.

I'm not seeing any other solution besides making some changes specific to being a chrome app, like wrapping the data files in a javascript method that sets the data straight at a javascript variable.

Please feel free to let me know of a better way to deal with this :)

FYI - Here's the error when you don't run the page sandboxed

Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

This happens here, I assume when it is trying to parse the data loaded via one of the async ethods:
 ( d3.v3.min.js:3
(anonymous function) d3.v3.min.js:3
e.parseRows d3.v3.min.js:3
e.parse d3.v3.min.js:3
r d3.v3.min.js:3
u d3.v3.min.js:1)

d3 is (I think) doing a new Function or something there that violates the CSP.

Comment: What shows up in the console?

Comment: @ChristopherHackett I added some info at the end of the post.  Once I went ahead and loaded the data via just wrapping the json with a "var newvar=" and include the script that way, it worked ok.